# How to use preg_match()/preg_replace() on specific lengths and patterns

Tags: php, preg-replace

I'm having so much trouble understanding this, could someone explain it?

I'm extremely concerned about sanitizing data on my website and I'd like to go the extra mile and strip everything that's not supposed to be there. here's an example I end up handling a lot of hex values which only contain hyphens, numbers and letters A through F in a string like this

```
7d43637d-780c-4703-8467-13525d590
```

How would I go about writing a preg_match/replace that would check for
8 characters '0-9' 'A-F' 'a-f', hyphen, 4 chars, hyphen, 4 chars, hyphen, 4 chars, hyphen, 9 chars?

Would it go a bit like this?

```
pre_replace("/([0-9a-fA-F]{8})\/([-])\/([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\/([-])\/([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\/([-])\/([0-9a-fA-F]{4})\/([-])\/([0-9a-fA-F]{9})\", "", $string);
```

I'm sorry it's so long and confusing, I am definitely open to alternative ideas to accomplish this.

I also need one that will check 'A-Z' 'a-z' '0-9' '-' '_' and 32 characters long

I really wish there was an online generator for this, maybe if I can understand how it is done I'll build one for other poor souls.

---

**Edit**

Using AbraCadaver's code I was able to get this to work using

```
if(!preg_match("/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{9}/i", $string)){
    echo 'error';
} else {
    //continue code
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why are you using `preg_replace`?

Comment: @casimir-et-hippolyte How would I do this/Am I doing it right?

Comment: @Barmar Cause I want to still be able to use the input?

Comment: But you're replacing everything that you want to allow with `""`. That seems to be the opposite of what you said.

Comment: What are all the `\/` in the regexp for? You didn't say you wanted to allow `/`.

Comment: @Barmar ohh Sorry, I want to ONLY allow the 0-9 a-f, I don't understand the replace string at all that's my problem

Comment: `preg_replace` replaces anything that matches the regular expression with the replacement. Unfortunately, negating a regular expression is hard.

Comment: Does the matching string appear just once in the input? In that case, you can do `preg_replace('/.*(regexp).*/', '$1', $input)`. This keeps the matching part, throws away everything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close but have alot more than needed.  Also, the `i` makes it case insensitive (A or a):

```
"/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{9}/i"
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/vDGkyGz-45z7nFZX)

```
if(!preg_match("/[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{4}-[0-9A-F]{9}/i", $string)) {
    echo "Invalid string";
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this in a preg_replace and it's not doing anything.. will this only work in a preg_match and output a true or false? or can I make it strip everything that doesn't fit also?

Comment: I reread your question.  This will match strings and if it doesn't match then throw it out as valid input.  I don't see how you can replace invalid characters in a string and have it conform to your requirements.

Comment: Well I bent my need around the bool and it works perfectly! Guess there isn't much to do about it being wrong anyways, this however helps me understand how the strings work now so thanks!